# JDBC insert error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert

I am trying to insert some data into my database with jdbc. I am using the correct table, db name, and parameters. Everything is checked.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException/*, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException*/ {
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter employee ID : ");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int empid = Integer.parseInt(d.readLine());

    System.out.println("Enter employee name : ");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String empname = d.readLine();

    System.out.println("Enter employee ID : ");
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    double empsalary = Double.parseDouble(d.readLine());

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection con;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB","root","");
        PreparedStatement  pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into `employee` values(?,?,?");
        pst.setInt(1, empid);
        pst.setString(2, empname);
        pst.setDouble(3, empsalary);
        int rowcount = pst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(rowcount + " row has been instered");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here are the errors that it gives me when I try to run it:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
at com.test.jdbcExample.main(jdbcExample.java:47)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in this line:

```
PreparedStatement  pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into `employee` values(?,?,?");
```

You are missing the closing parenthesis for the values clause.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing closing parenthesis in the values clause.

```
PreparedStatement  pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into employee values(?,?,?)");
```

Comment: i read that from mysql forum and without quotes i have the same problems

Comment: @Seekerakos There's also the missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Seekerakos The main problem is the missing closing parentheses, however you normally also specify the columns you are inserting into. Your current insert will break if columns are added or if the order of columns in the table changes.

Comment: yes i solve it gmarintes said the same thank u guys for your time !!